# Confused about Testing and Proper Placement of Method Taking a FileName as Parameter

Tags: c#, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I have a piece of code that generates a class, Id3v1Tag, using a file path to an .mp3 file. I am using it in a WPF MVVM app and, like many others, have become obsessed with designing my applications the 'right' way, so I am trying to figure out where to put the piece of code. Initially it was in the constructor for Id3v1Tag (inherited code base), but I took it out and put in a class called Id3v1TagService. But what about testing? Since it takes a filename as a parameter, isn't it now dependent on the file service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate the loading of the file from the other logic in your service.  The fact that the source may exist on disk identified by filename is not relevant to Id3v1TagService.  Instead pass it a stream.  The logic about opening/closing the file belongs in a different class.

This is a better design because:-

- Concerns are separated
- You can test Id3v1TagService without needing to fit the filesystem
- Id3v1TagService can now be used with data arriving via https, from a database, etc.

You will still need to test the class that opens/reads/closes the file.  It's inevitable that this needs to hit the filesystem (since that's the point).  You could leave this to integration tests if it's trivial and not have a unit test.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to pass in your file access object, whatever it is (this is part of dependency injection)  because then you can mock it down the road and test ONLY the functionality of the class you are trying to test.

The repository class, or service, or whatever is doing your file access, should use the filepath in it.